# How to toggle a specific div on click an image coming from ngfor loop in angular 11

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have multiple sections that contains info image and the details , when I click the info image specific details should toggle. All the images and divs are inside loop. Every thing is working fine but when I click another image without closing previous details, it keeps remain open. Previous section should close when I click on other image. Here is the code below
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nrys31?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

### app.component.html

```
<hello name="{{ name }}"></hello>
<h3>How to show info of clicked image only </h3>
<div *ngFor="let  x of things; let i = index">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/150/150" alt="loading" (click)="clicked(i)" >
  <div *ngIf="x.show">
    <div class="names">
      <div class="fullName">{{x.data}}</div>
      <div>{{x.data2}}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

### app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';
  public show:boolean = false;
      clicked(index) {// only show clicked img info 
        console.log(this.things[index]);
        this.things[index].show = !this.things[index].show;
      };

    public things:Array<any> = [{
    data: "information for img1:",
    data2: "only the info img1 is displayed",
    show: false
  },
    {
      data: "information for img2:",
      data2: "only the info for img2 is displayed"
    },
    {
      data: "information for img3:",
      data2: "only the  info for img3 is displayed"
    }]
}
```

Comment: You can take a variable in class level and stored the index over there. Whenever a block is clicked, close the prev opened block and update the prev to the new one.

Comment: Already using ngif again why we need class to hide it

Comment: The show property of the last clicked image needs to be updated to false while setting the show property of the currently clicked image to true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you click on any image you're toggling the **show property** of that image only.

`this.things[index].show = !this.things[index].show;`

This means that if any previous image is opened it will stay open alongside other images.

To solve this problem you have to create a variable that will hold an index of the clicked image and will use to set **show property** of the image to **false** whenever a new image will be clicked.

**Solution**

- Create Variable:

  - `previousIndex: number = -1;`
- Update clicked function

  ```
    clicked(index) {
   // Checking if same picture clicked or new
   if (this.previousIndex >= 0 && this.previousIndex != index) {
     //  If new picture is clicked then closing previous picture
     this.things[this.previousIndex].show = false;
   }
   // Updating index
   this.previousIndex = index;
   this.things[index].show = !this.things[index].show;
  ```

  }

[Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zvgfiw?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Answer (score 0):

you ca use angular services to store `things` :

and use properties like data and should_hide

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class YourServiceService {
  constructor( ) {

    this.things = [
      {  data: "yourData1", should_hide: false },
{  data: "yourData2", should_hide: true },
]
```

and toggle it based on should_hide in `ngif` inside `ngfor`

> Here is updated stackblitz

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ozjttg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: I did not understand, also why we need to use service for small thing

Comment: you can put the array of object in same file but services are good because you may want to get this from api in future

Comment: i have updated answer with stackblitz , please have a look

Comment: @Amrit Opened image will always stay open with your logic.